# Decimal to Boolean vb.net

Tags: boolean, decimal, vb.net-2010

I have come across this bit of vb.net code:

```
Protected Sub PremiumCalculation(grossPremiumIncldIpt As Decimal, netPremium As Decimal, ipt As Decimal, commission As Decimal)

Dim needCalcGrossPrem As Boolean = grossPremiumIncldIpt = Decimal.MinValue
```

Yet the compiler does not even try to assign a decimal to a Boolean !
Furthermore the app will run with no errors whatsoever! Even if I have `Option Strict` On` at the top of the file !

I have never ever seen a line of code like this before and can't understand why it isn't an invalid type cast or why it works.

Has anyone else encountered this, if so could they explain :S

Comment: Its ok, I've just answered my own question.

Comment: The declaration and assignment is identical to: If grossPremiumIncldIpt = Decimal.MinValue Then needCalcGrossPrem = True Else needCalcGrossPrem = False EndIf

Be interesting to see if this shortcut exists in C# !